# node to publish COG/ZMP

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anybody knows if there is a node to publish COG/ZMP from joint_state or tf of the robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42971/node-to-publish-cog/zmp/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just published [hrl_kinematics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hrl_kinematics) which consists of a small library and a node to do exactly that. From a URDF with joint state, you can compute the CoG and a projection to the supporting plane. You can also specify the supporting links (feet) and check of the pose is statically stable. There is not much documentation on the wiki, but the code is pretty self-explanatory I would say.

There's no ZMP in there yet -- I would happily accept patches!

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) on 2013-01-25**:
How can I submit patches?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-01-25**:
Best use the tracker for the alufr-ros-pkg repository: http://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/issues/list

**Comment by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) on 2013-01-25**:
Will do, Thanks!